# managemnt tab in kaa sandbox URL

Tags: kaa

I created Kaa sandbox instance on the AWS Linux host. I am getting some of the issues

1. Still I am not able to see the management button on the kaa Sandbox console.
2. I am not able to connect AWS with using ssh. I followed all the required step to connect to AWS Linux host, but not lucky to connect.

My problem is that, I would like to change the host IP in the sandbox setting with my AWS linux host IP, so that my end point device gets connected to host,

Still I am struggling with above points. Please advise.

Regards,
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be an issue with the Kaa 0.10.0 Sandbox for AWS. We created a [bug](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KSF-116) for tracking this.

For now, you can use the next workaround:

```
echo "sudo sed -Ei 's/(gui_change_host_enabled=).*$/\1true/'" \
"/usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/conf/sandbox-server.properties;" \
"sudo service kaa-sandbox restart" | \
ssh -i <your-private-aws-instance-key.pem> ubuntu@<your-aws-instance-host>
```

**Note**: this is a multi-line single command that works correctly in *bash* (should also work in *sh* and others, but that is not tested).

**Note 2**: don't forget to replace

```
<your-private-aws-instance-key.pem>
<your-aws-instance-host>
```

with the respective key name and host name/IP address.